# Listas Desplegables no funcionan correctamente en nueva versión de GoogleChrome (Materialize v 0.100.2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize, google-chrome

Sucede que al momento de querer abrir una lista desplegable de `Materialize V0.100.2` en `Google Chrome`, no se despliega correctamente y es necesario hacer dos o más click para poder ver las opciones correctamente.

Algunas veces funciona haciendo un solo click, otras no, y por eso estoy confundido y no se cual sea una posible solución. Intenté aplicando `e.preventDefault();` al evento `mouseup` y `mousedown`, pero no funcionó:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('select').material_select();

  $('.select-dropdown').on('mousedown', function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();

    //Se clickeó el mouse

  });

  $('.select-dropdown').on('mouseup', function(e) {
    //e.preventDefault();

    //Se soltó el mouse
  });

});
```

```html
<!--Import Google Icon Font-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s3">
      <select id="selectEstadoNotificacion">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Todos</option>
        <option value="done">Exito</option>
        <option value="failed">Fallido</option>
      </select>
      <label>Estado</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s3">
      <select id="jsChannelNotification">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Otro</option>
        <option value="done">Uno</option>
        <option value="failed">Dos</option>
      </select>
      <label>Medio</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de consular en foros y diferentes fuentes, al día de hoy no hay una solución concreta para este problema respecto a la nueva versión de ***Chrome*** y algunos componentes de ***Materialize Framework***, por lo tanto, realicé una solución que por el momento me funciona. Esto es una solución provicional mientras Google Chrome da un soporte frente a este inconveniente o hace algo al respecto. Pero por el momento, propongo esto:

**Básicamente, como el problema era dar doble click sobre la lista desplegable *(En Google Chrome)***, para mostrar las opciones, **entonces con el método *setTimeout()* programo un click en una pequeña fracción de tiempo**, para que el usuario solamente tenga que dar un click e *internamente damos el siguiente click*, y así, cuando se presente el error de desplegar las opciones, no se tendrá el problema de dar doble cilck sobre las listas para mostrar las opciones.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('select').material_select();

    $('body .select-dropdown').on('mousedown', function(e) {

      let thisElement = $(this);

      setTimeout(function() {
        $(thisElement).click();
      }, 350);
    });
});
```

```html
<!--Import Google Icon Font-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s3">
      <select id="selectEstadoNotificacion">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Todos</option>
        <option value="done">Exito</option>
        <option value="failed">Fallido</option>
      </select>
      <label>Estado</label>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field col s3">
      <select id="jsChannelNotification">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Otro</option>
        <option value="done">Uno</option>
        <option value="failed">Dos</option>
      </select>
      <label>Medio</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```